# print the 10th characher image on command line with assembler

Tags: assembly, codepages

The question is how to make command line show 10th charachter image (not new line feed). I've tried this code (using *TASM*):

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h
begin:
mov ah,2
mov dl,10
int 21h
ret
end begin
```

And here is the output (just new line feed):

[image]

I want to display 10th character image as in this picture:
[image]

My OS: Windows XP 32-bit

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 350 x86_64

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BIOS function 0Ah to do that.

```
mov cx,1
mov bx,7
mov ax,0A0Ah
int 10h
```